# (Prismatic) Plumatic Schema Documentation

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

I have been looking at using prismatic/schema for typing and documentation in clojure, but I have had trouble finding thorough documentation for it. The github readme provides some helpful basic usage information but leaves me with a lot of open questions (why do you need the "s" argument in (s/one s/Str "s") for instance). Does anyone know of a thorough tutorial or documentation source for prismatic schema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best place to start is the original Clojure Conj 2013 presentation:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_jtwIs2Ot8

Here are the various docs on GitHub:

- https://github.com/plumatic/schema
- http://plumatic.github.io/schema-0-2-0-back-with-clojurescript-data-coercion/
- http://plumatic.github.io/schema-for-clojurescript-data-shape-declaration-and-validation/
- https://github.com/plumatic/schema/wiki/Recursive-Schemas
- https://github.com/plumatic/schema/wiki/Defining-New-Schema-Types-1.0
- http://plumatic.github.io/schema/

Since they renamed it from `Prismatic` to `Plumatic` it looks like they have consolodated the old blog posts, etc to Plumatic github account. Other blog entries:

- https://camdez.com/blog/2015/08/27/practical-data-coercion-with-prismatic-schema/
- https://christopherdbui.com/an-overview-of-prismatics-schema-library-for-clojure/
- http://pygments.org/demo/1076301/
- http://codurance.com/2015/09/14/clojure-schemas-are-swagger/
- https://blog.juxt.pro/posts/component-meet-schema.html
- http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/02/prismatic-schema-coercion

Enjoy!